# User v3.5.3, EE v2.10.1

Tags: solspace-user

When User sends an invite it includes a Key.
     - Where is this key stored ?
     - Is there a way to generate a key without having a User be sent an invite ?
     - Is there a table which contains all the invites sent ?
     - Can the same key be shared with more than one User ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The keys are stored in the exp_user_keys database table. There is not a way to generate keys without sending an invite email. Multiple invites can be sent at the same time, but each user receives a different/unique key. :)